# How to get individual coordinates PCA in Python ? (Results different between R and Python)

Tags: python, r, coordinates, pca

I searched everywhere and answers i found don't work ...
I try to get coordinates of variables in Python but the solution i tried don't give me the same results than R

A)

```
Coordinates_Indiv = pca.fit_transform(df5)
Coordinates_Indiv = pd.DataFrame(Coordinates_Indiv)
```

B)

```
irlambdas=1/(5*np.sqrt(Explained_Variance))
mirlambadas=np.diagflat(irlambdas)
ProjectionsVars=df5.dot(df6)
ProjectionsVars2= ProjectionsVars.dot(mirlambadas)
```

with df6=df5.T

Has anyone an idea to solve it ?

Comment: Are you using `eigen` In R? If that is the case, The SVD-based PCA you are using in Python is likely to produce different results, because SVD and eigendecomposition handle negative eigenvalues differently.

Comment: First ,thank you so much for your answer and your time.

I am using the module Factominer and the summary(pca). For python i did it with sklearn (pca) but also with numpy

The thing is i got the same Eigenvalues in both cases between R and Python.But when i compute the individual coordinates , i get the same results between numpy and sklearn but not the same results than with R.

Answer (score 0):

First ,thank you so much for your answer and your time.

I am using the module Factominer and the summary(pca).
For python i did it with sklearn (pca) but also with numpy

The thing is i got the same Eigenvalues in both cases between R and Python 
(For python i computed it by using :

```
Correlation_Matrix = np.corrcoef(df)
Correlation_Matrix = np.nan_to_num(Correlation_Matrix)
Correlation_Matrix[np.diag_indices_from(Correlation_Matrix)] = 1

Eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(Correlation_Matrix)
Eigenvalues[Eigenvalues == 1] = 0
```

Or in a more easy way:

```
#Eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_)
```

In both case i got the same results than with R ... but when i compute the individual coordinates , i get the same results between numpy and sklearn but not the same results than with R.God only knows